# swapping object references in the method

Tags: java

In `Java` you can't do that without either wrapping into other objects or using arrays. This doesn't work.

```
a; // Object@12345
b; // Object@56789
swap(a, b);
a; // Object@12345
b; // Object@56789

void swap(Object a, Object b) {
     Object temp = a;
     a = b;
     b = temp;
}
```

But is there really no way to change the reference? Or can it be achieved using some unsafe workaround?

Comment: if ``a`` and ``b`` are local variables, there's no way other than swapping the references "manually".

Comment: @f1sh but shouldn't be there a way? I mean if the references can be assigned by JVM there must be a way to change them.

Comment: yes, there is way. Use the code of the ``swap`` method instead of calling it.

Comment: @f1sh using code is of course possible. I mean to pass the "pass by value" mechanism of Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables are only accessible within the method where they're declared.  When you call a different method, and pass values in, those values are copied to a new location on the stack.  The called method sees the new copies of those variables.  In other words, the variables `a` and `b` used in the `swap` method are different variables from the variables `a` and `b` in the calling method.  They have a different location on the stack.

So if you want to change the values of `a` and `b` in the calling method, you have to change them *in the same method*.  There is no way at all to perform this change in a separate method, like you've tried to do in your example.

Comment: But if changing object fields affects the original object, then there should be some way to update the original reference

Comment: @user1432980 no, exactly that is the difference. The reference is copied, so both the original and the copy point to the same object. That lets you modify that object. But changing the original reference cannot be done since you only have the copy available.

Comment: @user1432980 I don't see what you're getting at.  Objects are on the heap, so they don't "belong to" a particular method in the way that local variables and method parameters do.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem well I thought that the references of the object in the method is the same as the object outside it.

Comment: No, absolutely not.  An object always lives on the heap.  A reference can live on the stack or the heap, but it basically tells the JVM where to find the object.  Now there's no such thing as a variable that stores an object.  A variable of object type can only ever store a reference.  So it's important always to understand when you're changing a reference, and when you're changing an object.